# Python 2.7 pyperclip loop

Tags: python-2.7, loops, pyperclip

this is the current code:

```
import time
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("SO_site-packages"))
import pyperclip

recent_value = ""
while True:
    tmp_value = pyperclip.paste()
    if not tmp_value = recent_value:
        recent_value = tmp_value
        print("Value changed: %s" % str(recent_value)[:20])
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

**What I'm trying to do**: create a constant loop that waits for a user to copy text to clipboard, and print it whenever that happens.

**What happens currently**:  It only prints out the last copied item and stops.

**My question is**: How to make this code a listening loop?

Help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Do you get a traceback when it stops?

Comment: Your code already seems to be in a listening loop. I can run the script and it does print whenever and whatever text I copy. Am I understanding your question correctly?

Comment: It must be how i run it then? I press play on pycharm.. am i missing something?